# How to use ExcelCommand from ExcelDna

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-addins, excel-dna

I have a simple ExcelCommand:

```
[ExcelCommand(Name = "MyTestCommand", ShortCut = "^Q")]
public static void Teste()
{
    var xlApp = (Application)ExcelDnaUtil.Application;
    var ws = xlApp.Sheets[1] as Worksheet;
    var range = ws.Cells[1, 1] as Range;
    range.Value2 = "foo bar";
}
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>, cell A1 from the first sheet receives the text `"foo bar"`.

The client doesn't want a shortcut, he wants a user interface button (in Ribbon or in sheet body, doesn't matter).

With VBA I can write:

```
Sub Button1_OnClick()
    MyTestCommand
End Sub
```

But call `MyTestCommand` doesn't work.

How can I call my created command?

Answer (score 3):

If you set a value for the `MenuText` member of `ExcelCommand`, it will automatically become available through the `Add-Ins` ribbon.

[image]

```
[ExcelCommand(MenuText = "My Test Command", ShortCut = "^Q")]
public static void Teste()
{
    // ...
}
```

If you want more control over the look-and-feel of how the command is presented, then create your own `CustomUI`, with your own button, icon, etc. [Take a look at the different Ribbon examples that come with Excel-DNA](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/tree/master/Distribution/Samples/Ribbon).

Answer (score 1):

There is a VERY horrid frig that you could employ by using VBA's quirky SendKeys function. This would get things working without having to use the ribbon and would let you use standard buttons on your sheet.

ok, stand back and cover your eyes :)

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    ' this short cut invokes the
    ' MyTestCommand function
    SendKeys "^Q"
End Sub
```

endure, i mean *enjoy*

Comment: Nice (+1). But half measure (can't mark as correct).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Button1_OnClick()
    Application.Run("MyTestCommand")
End Sub
```